# Where does neo4j desktop store databases on Mac OS X?

Tags: neo4j

I simply can't figure out where the neo4j desktop app installs data ... I wan't to remove the bugger C O M P L E T E L Y, as it's a complete nightmare connecting the sucker to a node app ... sigh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to delete a Neo4j Desktop "project", but not the Desktop itself, you can tell the Desktop to delete it:

1. Open the `Neo4j Desktop`.
2. In the `Projects` panel on the left, hover your mouse over the project to delete, and click the recycling bin icon that appears on the right.
3. Confirm that you want to delete.

If you only want to know *where* the data for a specific Neo4j Desktop project is, there are several ways that the Desktop can tell you. For example (on a Mac):

1. Open the `Neo4j Desktop`.
2. In the `Projects` panel on the left, click on a project.
3. Click on the `Manage` button for the project.
4. Click on the `Open Folder` button (not the down-arrow to its right).
5. A Finder window will pop up, displaying the contents of the installation folder for that project. The project's data is under the `data` subfolder.

The above technique can also be used to find out where the Desktop stores all its projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer.

Answer (score 10):

The data for the app should be located at:

`~/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/`

Comment: this is the answer you want if the Neo4j Desktop UI stops working for some reason - like I experienced today - the software update breaks the UI